How to Extend Triggers on LexicalJS to autoupdate the current node once with @mentions LexicalJS?
Hi im struggling to find a solution on this im kinda new to lexical framework and im currently using it for a mentions feature on my app (social app).
I manage to extend a bit of the functionality of that mentionplugin they provide by default but i cant find a solution for my use case.
I basically want the creation/transformation of the mention node (because we just replace the current textnode to a mentionnode) to happen when its initially trigger so on the @ + a letter and at this moment it should trigger.
I provided the code with the onSelectOption that use that logic that i want to implement on the triggersFn that for the moment only accept the text and editor to look for mentionmatch.
Its like instead of having to click on the person that pops it should automatically create that mention node when we detect that @ join a letter and then propose for mentionmatch etc. Event if the person doesnt exist it should still be a mentionnode for ux purpose i guess..
Hmu if u guys need more info
export default function NewMentionsPlugin(): JSX.Element | null {
  const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();
  const [queryString, setQueryString] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const { results, loading } = useMentionLookupService(queryString);
  const checkForSlashTriggerMatch = useBasicTypeaheadTriggerMatch('/', {
    minLength: 0,
  });

  const options = useMemo(() => {
    if (results !== null) {
      return results.map((result: { name: any; image: any; username: any; }) => {
        const { name, image, username } = result;
        return new MentionTypeaheadOption(name, image, username);
      }).slice(0, SUGGESTION_LIST_LENGTH_LIMIT);
    }
    return [];
  }, [results]);
  const onSelectOption = useCallback(
    (
      selectedOption: { name: string; image: string; username: string },
      nodeToReplace: TextNode | null,
      closeMenu: () => void
    ) => {
      console.log(nodeToReplace)
      editor.update(() => {
        const mentionNode = $createMentionNode(selectedOption.username);
        if (nodeToReplace) {
          nodeToReplace.replace(mentionNode);
        }
        mentionNode.select();
        closeMenu();
      });
    },
    [editor]
  );
  
  //where im need to update the editor node to mention node with creatementionode
  const checkForMentionMatch = useCallback(
    (
      text: string,
      editor: LexicalEditor,
    ) => {
      console.log(text)
      const slashMatch = checkForSlashTriggerMatch(text, editor);
      if (slashMatch !== null) {
        return null;
      }

      return getPossibleQueryMatch(text);
    },
    [checkForSlashTriggerMatch, editor]
  );

  const parent = document.getElementById('parent') as HTMLElement | undefined;

  return (

    <LexicalTypeaheadMenuPlugin
      onQueryChange={setQueryString}
      onSelectOption={onSelectOption}
      triggerFn={checkForMentionMatch}
      options={options}
      anchorClassName="disable"
      menuRenderFn={(anchorElementRef, { selectedIndex, selectOptionAndCleanUp, setHighlightedIndex }) =>
        anchorElementRef.current ? (
          ReactDOM.createPortal(
            <>
              {loading ? (
                <div className='rounded-xl'>
                  <div className="overflow-y-auto max-h-52 rounded-xl bg-[rgba(16,16,16,1)]" id='main-pop'>
                    <div className='overflow-x-hidden  overflow-y-hidden flex items-center relative px-0 py-0 mx-0 my-0 w-full'>
                      <div className='flex flex-col flex-shrink w-full px-1 py-0.5'>
                        <div className='flex flex-row flex-wrap p-2'>
                          <div className='flex h-[36px] justify-center items-center mx-auto'>
                            <svg aria-label="Chargement…" className="animate-spin text-white opacity-60" role="img" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width={20} height={20}>
                              <rect fill="white" height="10" opacity="0" rx="5" ry="5" transform="rotate(-90 50 50)" width="28" x="67" y="45"></rect>
                              <rect fill="white" height="10" opacity="0.125" rx="5" ry="5" transform="rotate(-45 50 50)" width="28" x="67" y="45"></rect>
                              <rect fill="white" height="10" opacity="0.25" rx="5" ry="5" transform="rotate(0 50 50)" width="28" x="67" y="45"></rect>
                              <rect fill="white" height="10" opacity="0.375" rx="5" ry="5" transform="rotate(45 50 50)" width="28" x="67" y="45"></rect>
                              <rect fill="white" height="10" opacity="0.5" rx="5" ry="5" transform="rotate(90 50 50)" width="28" x="67" y="45"></rect>
                              <rect fill="white" height="10" opacity="0.625" rx="5" ry="5" transform="rotate(135 50 50)" width="28" x="67" y="45"></rect>
                              <rect fill="white" height="10" opacity="0.75" rx="5" ry="5" transform="rotate(180 50 50)" width="28" x="67" y="45"></rect>
                              <rect fill="white" height="10" opacity="0.875" rx="5" ry="5" transform="rotate(225 50 50)" width="28" x="67" y="45"></rect>
                            </svg>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ) : results.length > 0 ? (
                <div className='rounded-xl'>
                  <div className=" rounded-[16px] w-full overflow-x-hidden drop-shadow" id='main-pop'>
                    <div className='overflow-y-auto max-h-[285px]'>
                      <ul className='bg-[#1b1b1b]  flex flex-col'>
                        {options.map((option, i: number) => (
                          <MentionsTypeaheadMenuItem
                            index={i}
                            isSelected={selectedIndex === i}
                            onClick={() => {
                              setHighlightedIndex(i);
                              try {
                                selectOptionAndCleanUp(option);
                              } catch (error) {
                                console.error("Error in selectOptionAndCleanUp:", error);
                              }
                            }}
                            onMouseEnter={() => {
                              setHighlightedIndex(i);
                            }}
                            option={option}
                            key={i}
                          />
                        ))}
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ) : null}
            </>,
            anchorElementRef.current
          )
        ) : null
      }
    />

  );
}

i tryed this :
const checkForMentionMatch = useCallback(
  (
    text: string,
    editor: LexicalEditor,
  ) => {
    console.log(text)

    editor.update(() => {
      const selection = $getSelection();
      const node = selection?.getNodes()[0];
      const mentionNode = $createMentionNode(text);
      if (node) {
        node.replace(mentionNode);
      }
    });
    const slashMatch = checkForSlashTriggerMatch(text, editor);
    if (slashMatch !== null) {
      return null;
    }

    return getPossibleQueryMatch(text);
  },
  [checkForSlashTriggerMatch, editor]
);

but it will update the selection every query so like this:

instead of this:

